# jQuery get parent id not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not great with JavaScript/jQuery and am having a lot of trouble with a very basic task. I have an `img` that, when clicked, should give me the id of the parent `div` it is within.

This is the markup:

```
<div id="client-1">
    <img src="~/Content/plus.ico" alt="plus" onclick="ButtonExpandClick()" />
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ButtonExpandClick() {
        alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
    }
</script>
```

Clicking the image gives me an alert that says "undefined" but I can clearly see that the `div` has the id of "client-1" when I inspect the page. I must be missing something simple here. I've also tried using `.closest` as well as passing `this` into the function but no luck. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I recommend to read this article to learn how event handling with jQuery works: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `onclick` attribute for events.  You're using jQuery, bind the events "properly".

Add a class to the image(s):

```
<img src="~/Content/plus.ico" alt="plus" class="icon" />
```

Then bind the event:

```
$(function(){
    $('.icon').click(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there anything particularly bad about using the inline "onclick" event?

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot: It's just how I learned.  It's called ["Unobtrusive JavaScript"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Not 'evil' bad, but the concept of having things being unobtrusive simplifies management of code. Keep your styles in a css, your javascript in a js file, and your server code separated from your html output skeleton as much as possible. It is easier to read, maintain, and refactor each concern separately.

Comment: I understand the code but this doesn't seem to be working for me for some reason... The click doesn't come up with anything now.

Comment: Did you add the `class="icon"` and the `$(function(){ })`?  It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/baH84/

Comment: Ya, i literally copy pasted your code block and added the class. I must have something else broken. Im using MVC 4 and Vb and have had a pain getting jquery to work so far..

Comment: I tested this solution as well. It also works fine. If you are going to identify your 'expand-collapse' classes/images this way which correlate to a on click bind, I would recommend using a class name that relates to that for clarity.

Comment: ReferenceError: rootjQuery is not defined
return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery);

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot: What version of jQuery are you using?  What browser?

Comment: I am using firefox. And I have jquery-2.0.3.js in my Scripts folder of my mvc project.

Comment: Chrome gives me Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Project:55
WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost

Comment: Something is wrong with jQuery.  Not sure what.  I don't use MVC, so I don't know what issues that has with jQuery.

Comment: Ok ill look more into this problem, thank you for your jquery help within this question though.

Answer (score 1):

If you hook up the click event using jQuery instead of doing it inline, then you'll get the `this` passed in automatically:

Note that you'd have to give the image an `id` or find another selector for it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#myImg").click(ButtonExpandClick);
});
```

Comment: *"you'll get the `this` passed in automatically"*: That sounds a bit strange. `this` will *always* exist, the question is only which object/element it refers to.

Comment: Yeah, I worded it badly. What I mean is that the image control itself is available for use in the `ButtonExpandClick` function by using `this`. If you were writing it inline, `onclick="ButtonExpandClick(this)"` forces you to pass `this` into the function as a parameter, while hooking up the event elsewhere does not. I probably still could have worded that better :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in  `this`

```
onclick="ButtonExpandClick(this)"
```

**JS**

```
function ButtonExpandClick(elem) {
   alert($(elem).parent().attr("id"));
}
```

Also it is a bad idea to declare inline events . Attach the event directly using javascript.

```
<script>

   $(function() {
       $('#client-1 img').click(function() {
           alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
       });
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, your inline solution seems to be working for me. Oddly, the unobtrusive js doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jquery.click or send your element with function. like sendme(this).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function(e) {
            var id = this.parentNode.id; //Using javascript to access id is faster.
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Example working at [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JmCRS/)

It's recommended put this images inside a container. and change this to. It's better for performance.

$(function() {

```
   var images = $('#container').find('img');
   images.on('click', function(e) {
        var id = this.parentNode.id; //Using javascript to access id is faster.
        alert(id);
    });

});
```

Comment: Then presumably `this.parentNode.id` would be even faster?

Comment: Sure thing...improving :)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler still you might try this with a binding:

```
<div id="client-1">
  <img src="~/Content/plus.ico" alt="plus"  />
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function(){
      // Two ways to do the same thing
      alert(this.parentNode.id);
      alert($(this).parent()[0].id);
    });
  });
</script>
```